# Software for image editing a portion of a PDF page without having to cut and paste?

Tags: adobe-acrobat, editing

I do layouts of photos, eight to a page, each in a separate photo border box and received in PDF format.

I would like to be able to do separate editing to each one (contrast, lighten, darken, etc) just as I do in Word - nothing too technical, very simple.

Any suggestions as to a version of Adobe or a plug-in which allows editing only a portion of the page, without having to cut and paste or import and export to another program?

There's lots out there for high-tech professionals, but I was hoping to find an easy way for amateurs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure I understood the question correctly: do you already have a PDF with multiple images arranged on a page in a grid and need to adjust the individual images without changing the layout?

[image]

In this case, you could import the PDF into [GIMP](http://gimp.org) then use selection tools to select an individual image (if the photos have single-color boxes around them or if the background is white or some single-color, it will be very easy), edit whatever you like inside the selection only, select next, repeat... Then export it back as PDF.

The only thing you need to take care of is resolution: When importing into GIMP, select a resolution that is large enough (at least as large as the one your PDF-embedded photos are in), or less you will lose information. Also note that, since GIMP converts everything to bitmap, any selectable/copyable text in that PDF will be gone (it will be treated as an image).

Comment: Converting a PDF page into one large image is generally not a good idea. I would only do that if there is no other way to edit the file.